# dynamically create comboboxes with javascript and assign the same list

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, combobox

I have a user interface that must create comboboxes dynamically while the user is adding information to a form. The contents (options in a select tag) are going to be the same for all of them. I'm using a viewmodel for this but I can't get it to work. This is what I have so far in a jquery click event for a button:

```
var idCounter = "UserId" + counter;
    var html = '<select class="form-control" id=idCounter><option value="">--Select --</option></select >';

$(html).appendTo("#SomeDiv");

let selectelement = document.getElementById('UserId');

//code something similar to:
Model.Users.ForEach((user) => {
                console.log(option.id);
                console.log(option.value);
                var option = document.createElement('option');
                option.id = user.UserId;
                option.value = user.Username;
                selectelement.appendChild();
            });
```

`Model` doesn't exist, but `@Model` would be a server side action, and that's what I want to avoid. I tried assigning info from the model to a local javascript variable but it won't work because the variable would not be in the same context. And the number of comboboxes can't be determined prior to serving the page to the client.

Is there a way I could achieve this?

Comment: you should  pass the data via namespaced object

Comment: Why not just create one `<select>` element correctly using `@Html.DropDownListFor()` to populate the options and then clone it

Comment: The alternative is to assign `Model.Users` to a javascript array using `var users = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Users))` and then loop through it

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I get an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" using Json.Encode

Comment: That means that `Users` is `null`

Comment: I was sending the wrong type to the view, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the data from your view model in the razor view using C# code and store it into a js variable and use that in your other part of script. Use name spacing to avoid potential overwriting of global js variables.

```
<script>
    var myApp = myApp || {};
    myApp.Users = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Users));
</script>
<script src="~/Scripts/myfile.js"></script>
```

Now in your script file (`myfile.js`), You can access `myApp.Users`.

```
(function($,window,myApp) {
    $(function () {

        console.log('myApp users are here');    
        console.log(myApp.Users);
        //use myApp.Users array as needed

    });

})(jQuery,window,myApp);
```